# identify each iphone device in iOS SDK

Tags: iphone, xcode, uuid, uidevice

I need to determine each iOS device.

In the past SDKS, there's a way to identify UUID by the command

```
 [[UIDevice currentDevice] uniqueIdentifier];
```

But in iOS 5.0, this function is deprecated. Is there any way to do this similar task?

Thank you!

Comment: What are you trying to do with the UUID?

Comment: Check This [Tutorial](http://oleb.net/blog/2011/09/how-to-replace-the-udid/) about how to create UDID in ios5.

Comment: Check Apple documentation about CFUUIDRef:
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/CoreFoundation/Reference/CFUUIDRef/Reference/reference.html

Comment: Possibile duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7273014/ios-unique-user-identifier

Answer (score 3):

> [uniqueIdentifier](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIDevice_Class/DeprecationAppendix/AppendixADeprecatedAPI.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIDevice/uniqueIdentifier)
>
> An alphanumeric string unique to each device based on various hardware
>   details. (read-only) (Deprecated in iOS 5.0. Instead, create a unique
>   identifier specific to your app.) @property (nonatomic, readonly,
>   retain) NSString *uniqueIdentifier Special Considerations
>
> Do not use the uniqueIdentifier property. To create a unique
>   identifier specific to your app, you can call the CFUUIDCreate
>   function to create a UUID, and write it to the defaults database using
>   the NSUserDefaults class. Availability
>
> ```
> Available in iOS 2.0 and later.
> Deprecated in iOS 5.0.
> ```
>
> Related Sample Code
>
> ```
> GKTank
> ```
>
> Declared In UIDevice.h

So use CFUUIDCreate and you will get and uniqID and save it to the NSUDefaults.
Note that the CFUUIDCreate will give you a new id on each call. That is why you have to save it.

If you really need to know if the app was installed on that device you can read the mac address of the wifi card.

Answer (score 3):

For iOS 6 and latter you can use.

> NSString *U_ID = [[NSUUID UUID] UUIDString];

Answer (score 1):

Please check the answer of @suchi here [How to create a GUID/UUID using the iPhone SDK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/427180/how-to-create-a-guid-uuid-using-the-iphone-sdk).

use [[UIDevice currentDevice] uniqueDeviceIdentifier] to retrieve the unique identifier (it's a hash of your Bundle ID + MAC address)

use [[UIDevice currentDevice] uniqueGlobalDeviceIdentifier] to retrieve a global unique identifier (it's a hash of the MAC address, used for tracking between different apps).