# Paid App : need to uniquely ID the user

Tags: iphone, uniqueidentifier

I am designing a *paying* app that will require users to create their own profile.

This app will of course be downloadable on each of the devices the user has.

This is the precise scenario I want to bypass :

1. the user downloads the App on an iPhone
2. he creates an account and start using the app that makes server
   calls
3. he downloads the app on his iPad and with his login & password
   retreives the data on the server, so far so good
4. Now, he lends his iPad to a friend (who didn't pay for the app).
5. The friend wants to use the App, and wants to create his own
   account. Yet, I want to forbide this since he didn't pay for the
   App.

So my problem is : I want to restrict the use of the app only to the user that paid for the App, not for his friend.

Of course, I cannot use the AppleID since there is no way to reach it from code.

I thought one moment that I could use iCloud like mentioned here but since the ( [iOS unique user identifier](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7273014/ios-unique-user-identifier) )user can choose not to use iCloud, my problem is not solved ...

Is there an easy solution that I missed to solve that issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You friend will be using different apple id. You could use Restoring Transactions api of apple to get understand whether the user has purchased the app or not. This is possible for non-consumable in app purchase. Please do check the below link : 
 https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/StoreKitGuide/MakingaPurchase/MakingaPurchase.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008267-CH3-SW1

Comment: Hi, well, the friend won't necessarily use another Apple ID if he stays logged on the buyer's accound.  I will check the link you gave  me.

Comment: Then what you think to implement is not possible.. Same apple id and same device? How could the device identify who is playing??

Comment: I know, I thought there would be a solution ... Thx anyway !