# Why did my unique device ID change?

Tags: ios, xcode, uniqueidentifier

I have been using the following method for around a month with no problem. The device ID remained the same even after uninstalls of the app. Recently I noticed that my device ID changed. I have been doing a lot of builds of the app recently on Xcode6. Could this be a cause? I wish I knew exactly when it changed. It caught me by surprise. Do I have anything to worry about when the app goes on the app store? Maybe this is just an Xcode build problem? I am just looking for a simple way to guarantee a unique device ID. I would use advertisingIdentifer but I hear using it for purpose other then advertisements will get rejected by app store. Here is the code:

```
+ (NSString *)getUserID
{
    NSString *Appname = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] infoDictionary] objectForKey:@"CFBundleName"];
    NSString *retrieveuuid = [SSKeychain passwordForService:Appname account:@"user"];

    if(retrieveuuid == NULL)
    {
        CFUUIDRef newUniqueId = CFUUIDCreate(kCFAllocatorDefault);
        retrieveuuid = (__bridge_transfer NSString*)CFUUIDCreateString(kCFAllocatorDefault, newUniqueId);
        CFRelease(newUniqueId);
        [SSKeychain setPassword:retrieveuuid forService:Appname account:@"user"];
    }

    NSLog(@"%@", retrieveuuid);
    return retrieveuuid;
}
```

Comment: As a sidenote: a better choice to use would be `-[UIDevice identifierForVendor]`. See [the docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/iOS/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIDevice_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIDevice/identifierForVendor).

Comment: probably you have restarted your device.

Comment: @Riley to my knowledge the identifierForVendor will change if they uninstall all of my apps. I don't want the id to ever change when they uninstall my app.

Comment: @user4233467 Yes, I believe that is true. I'm not sure that what you want exists (I'm not sure it doesn't exist, either - I just don't know).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The unique device id does not persist  This has been asked many times before and you should  find some good info on here.  A quick Google search brings up the following.

https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=iOS+UDID+replacement

[Persistent UDID equivalent for iOS 7?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21095686/persistent-udid-equivalent-for-ios-7)

[UIDevice uniqueIdentifier Deprecated - What To Do Now?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6993325/uidevice-uniqueidentifier-deprecated-what-to-do-now)

[iOS unique user identifier](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7273014/ios-unique-user-identifier)

general advice is to use `CFUUID` to create your own `UUID`, then persist it in the `keychain`

Comment: Isn't that what my method is doing? :S