# CrossDeviceInfo.Current.Id on iOS Not Consistent

Tags: ios, iphone, cross-device

Why on iPhone iOS 8 does CrossDeviceInfo.Current.Id not return a consistent device ID like it does on Windows and Android devices? It changes daily...

Comment: That plugin uses `identifierForVendor` so it should be consistent for each *installlation* of your app on a given device. During development it may well change as you reinstall the app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't get consistent device ID in iOS, it was available before iOS 5.
See this post to get full idea about device id in iOS. 
[See here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27276645/why-did-my-unique-device-id-change)