# Persistant UDID alternate

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, udid

i Know this question already been asked many times and I can put here many links for references like the one of them [Persistant UDID alternate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21095686/persistent-udid-equivalent-for-ios-7). And I fount this [link](https://possiblemobile.com/2013/04/unique-identifiers/) for detailing about each identifier but every one telling us one solution to create from server and assign to user, as Facebook or Game Center doing.

- Is this possible that we create this from device side and that should be persistant always.
- Will apple reject if we use UDID in and doing some amend by some specific formula and send to server?

Looking for answer.

Answer (score 0):

Store the UDID/UUID in the keychain as a password, it's the best way to solve your problem.

I recommend you to look for keychain wrappers in github and choose one of them. It will make your life much easier.