# Unique Identification of iOS device for iOS 7.0 and above

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios7

Looking for your help

I am facing a problem while getting **Device Identifier**. Actually I am using a UIDevice+IdentifierAddition.h, NSString+MD5Addition.h  classes to get Identifier, but its **return same identifier for all my devices** i.e. **iPhone 4s (iOS 7.1) & iPhone 5 (iOS 7.1.1).**

Can any one have any solution for this problem. because I want a something unique for device specific. its my app requirement.

**Important: I want to submit this app on app store, So please, answer must be as per the guidelines**

Comment: Have you check with the UUID ..? **https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSUUID_Class/Reference/Reference.html**

Comment: possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7273014/ios-unique-user-identifier/8677177#8677177

Comment: @KumarKL Thanks for your reply. its return UUID which means its give different identifier on every launch of app. I need something like UDID. Which will be unique for every device.

Comment: @MateuszSzlosek  thanks for your reply. if you had gone through with the link you provide me there is a comment by Drabuna that it return new UUID every time. But I need something unique which is a device specific like UDID.

Comment: @karam There's a solution with storing UUID in keychain. You'll generate this once and later read this value from keychain on the next launch.

Comment: @MateuszSzlosek thanks for your reply. I have already implemented it. Hope apple will not have any issue with it.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Since iOS 7 it is no longer possible to get any unique device identifiers.

Your options are:

- create your own unique ID and [save it in the keychain](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7273014/ios-unique-user-identifier/8677177#8677177).
- use the [vendor ID](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIDevice_Class/Reference/UIDevice.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006902-CH3-SW49), which will be reset if all the app by the same vendor are removed from the device.

Comment: +1 and to be complete, here is the link saying that the unique device identifiers stopped after iOS6.1 https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIDevice_Class/DeprecationAppendix/AppendixADeprecatedAPI.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIDevice/uniqueIdentifier

Comment: @rckoenes thanks for your reply. I have already implemented it. Hope apple will not have any issue with it.

Comment: @rckoenes-for the 1st option(create your own unique ID and save it in the keychain.)  Is there a way user can reset this by reseting location and privacy on one's device or by a factory reset?

Comment: @rakappdev Yes it is possible that the user resets this. But if the user has their keychain in the cloud you value should be saved there. Another option is to save the key on the user iCloud drive. But there is not way to restrict it to a phyiscal device not should you.

Answer (score 15):

Now it's possible in **iOS 11.0+**, Apple has introduced a new API called `DeviceCheck API` with which developers can uniquely identify a device.

As mentioned in [the documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/devicecheck):

> Using the DeviceCheck APIs, in combination with server-to-server APIs,
>   you can set and query two bits of data per device, while maintaining
>   user privacy. You might use this data to identify devices that have
>   already taken advantage of a promotional offer that you provide, or to
>   flag a device that you have determined to be fraudulent. The
>   DeviceCheck APIs also let you verify that the token you receive comes
>   from an authentic Apple device that includes your app.

Also, check out the following WWDC17 video starting at 24 min:
https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2017/702/

---

**EDIT:**

A thoroughly detailed tutorial on this `Device Check` topic can be found [here](https://fluffy.es/devicecheck-tutorial/?utm_campaign=AppCoda%20Weekly&utm_medium=email&utm_source=Revue%20newsletter).

Comment: This will work a bit differently then a Unique identifier, as you can not store this on your server. But it does allow your app to store 2 bits, yes 2 bits, of data on a server at Apple. Which it can retrieve in the app.

Comment: The WWDC17 video seems to be no longer available

Answer (score 8):

In Objective c

```
NSString *uniqueIdentifier = [[[UIDevice currentDevice] identifierForVendor] UUIDString];
```

In Swift

```
 var uniqueId=UIDevice.currentDevice().identifierForVendor.UUIDString as String
 println("Your device identifires =>\(uniqueId)")
```

Comment: This will change each time that the application is re-installed. It's not a true UDID.

Comment: @NathanFiscaletti Are you testing on simulator ? test on real device.

Comment: No, I'm testing on real devices. The way that identifierForVendor works is that once all apps from the vendor are removed the identifierForVendor is reset to a new identifier. It's only meant for sharing a value between a specific vendors applications.

Comment: @NathanFiscaletti Thanks. identifierForVendor is the same for apps that come from the same vendor running on the same device. A different value is returned for apps on the same device that come from different vendors, and for apps on different devices regardless of vendor.   Instead, use NSUUID to generate a custom UUID and store that in the keychain (because the keychain isn't deleted if the app is deleted and reinstalled).

Answer (score 5):

Unfortunately identifierForVendor changes when you uninstall your application so to guarantee that the it will not change save it in the keychain

I used pod 'SSKeychain' Homepage: https://github.com/soffes/sskeychain

Here is the code

```
 + (NSString *)getDeviceId {
           NSString *appName=[[[NSBundle mainBundle] infoDictionary] objectForKey:(NSString*)kCFBundleNameKey];
           NSString *strApplicationUUID = [SSKeychain passwordForService:appName account:@"MY_KEY"];
           if (strApplicationUUID == nil) {
               strApplicationUUID  = [[[UIDevice currentDevice] identifierForVendor] UUIDString];
               [SSKeychain setPassword:strApplicationUUID forService:appName account:@"MY_KEY"];
            }
    return strApplicationUUID;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

[UIDevice uniqueIdentifier]; is deprecated in ios 5 and above.

You can get identifier for vendor using this 
NSString *udid = [[UIDevice currentDevice] uniqueIdentifier];

and store this in keychain and use later on.

Also you can check for 
1) NSUUID
2)CFUUID

you will get detail description here [Unique device identification in ios](https://possiblemobile.com/2013/04/unique-identifiers/)

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to identify a device only once i.e., to estimating the number of unique users then I suggest using "advertisingIdentifier" of ASIdentifierManager.

[Apple Doc](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/AdSupport/Reference/ASIdentifierManager_Ref/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/ASIdentifierManager/advertisingTrackingEnabled)