# How can you uniquely identify an iOS device?

Tags: ios, device, uuid

In more recent iOS versions you are not allowed to use iOS UUID anymore. Is there any way to uniquely identify an iOS device using any other alternative?

From what I have noticed, Facebook app will identify your account even after you delete the app and reinstall it. How is that possible?

Would using Mac address of the iOS device work?

Comment: You can store data in keychain storage

Comment: Won't keychain storage be deleted after the app is deleted?

Comment: No it is not deleted.

Comment: Think very hard about why you want to identify the _device_ at all. Think about how your app would get confused when I sold my phone on eBay and bought a new one. Except for asset management (a company wanting to keep track of where all their iPhones are) there are very few cases where identifying a device is the right thing to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The closest thing we have to the uuid is the [vendor id](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIDevice_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIDevice/identifierForVendor) now

Comment: iOS11+ new API called `DeviceCheck` can uniquely identify a device, check answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24753537/unique-identification-of-ios-device-for-ios-7-0-and-above/45711623#45711623

Comment: @IceCode awesome