# In-app user identification with Apple ID

Tags: ios, swift, authentication, in-app-purchase

Hope somebody is familiar with this issue. There is an app an d related web service. The registration on the back-end requires login (email or username) and password. During Appstore review process we were informed that we are not allowed to ask appstore users to go through our registration  form.  And there we are stuck, what to do next? It is known that there is no way to get any unique key from Apple ID (forbidden due to privacy terms again) nor email.

So the questions is how to identify user of app if he changed on another device?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24753537/unique-identification-of-ios-device-for-ios-7-0-and-above

Comment: AFAIK there is no policy on the [App Store Review Guidelines](https://developer.apple.com/app-store/review/guidelines/) that prevent you from requiring users to login/register to use your app. Perhaps the problem is the registration form itself. Are you using a webview, hosted on a server for registration or is the form native?

Comment: I am using native in app form with my API.

Comment: Could it be that you are asking for the wrong information, like their Apple ID and password?

Comment: My app is client of vpn Web Service. It requires only email and password. Thats a answer of Apple review stuff "Your app requires users to register with personal information to access non account-based features, which is not allowed on the App Store. 
User registration that requires the sharing of personal information must be optional or tied to account-specific functionality."

And I don't understand how identify user on backend... if I can't get email, username or else.

Comment: The clause is point two of the [Data Collection and Storage](https://developer.apple.com/app-store/review/guidelines/#data-collection-and-storage) policy. The fact that it is a VPN service indicates to me that registration is "relevant to the core functionality". Have you tried escalating the review? I know there are number of VPN apps that require login/register.

Comment: I use 1password and it sync the database with my apple id using oAuth through a webpage... But in 1P iOS App... it doesn't ask my Apple ID and can also sync database, i am sure that's what you want but I am also curious how 1P do this :(