# Getting two different device IDs from same iphone

Tags: ios, iphone, swift3, udid

I am getting different UDIDs for my iphone when i get it [from itunes](https://www.innerfence.com/howto/find-iphone-unique-device-identifier-udid) and programatically like this

```
UDID:String = UIDevice.current.identifierForVendor!.uuidString
```

Basically im trying to acquire a unique identifier for my iphone just like we have mac address for android phones.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Unique Identification of iOS device for iOS 7.0 and above](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24753537/unique-identification-of-ios-device-for-ios-7-0-and-above)

Comment: You can not obtain the UDID programmatically.  `identifierForVendor` is a unique identifier but it can change if your app is deleted and reinstalled.

Comment: yes but  as adarshaU mentioned (accepted answer) , we can store the UDID in keychain and keep it restrained for the device despite the reinstallation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

one easiest way is to solve this issue by storing the identifierForVendor in keychain. even if you uninstall app ,value for the key remains same and its unchanged. many third party libraries available to perform this . one of them https://github.com/jrendel/SwiftKeychainWrapper.

```
func getGlobalUniqueIdentifierFromKeyChain()->String{

    let retrievedString: String? = KeychainWrapper.standard.string(forKey: "DeviceId")

    if  retrievedString == nil{
        if let deviceKey  = UIDevice.current.identifierForVendor?.uuidString{
            let _ = KeychainWrapper.standard.set(deviceKey, forKey: "DeviceId")
        }
    }

    if let globalID = KeychainWrapper.standard.string(forKey: "DeviceId"){
        return globalID
    }else{
        return UIDevice.current.identifierForVendor?.uuidString ?? ""
    }
}
```

Comment: after IOS 7 , this seems to be the best approach . Works like a charm thankyou