# unable to have a unique ios device, as advertising identifier returned as 00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000 after ios 10

Tags: ios, ios10, idfa

I used to use apples advertising identifier as the Unique device ID key, to keep a track of users device, But with upgrade to iOS 10 and limit ad tracking returning `IDFA as 00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000`, I am unable to maintain the device records, Is there any other replacement which I can use for device id to be stored unique to a user as he signs up.

Comment: Your app is using Ad?

Comment: yes,we are using it

Comment: Now you need Unique device ID for ad or for other use?

Comment: For Ad its fine if I dont get but I need Unique device ID for maintaining a record of User, and this ID was the primary key to distinguish each device of user

Comment: You can use `identifierForVendor` or generate your own UUID

Comment: identifierForVendor keeps chnaging again and again, can you send me any link to gernerate your own UDID

Comment: identifierForVendor change only if you uninstall and reinstall app. Are you getting different identifierForVendor on simple relaunch of app?

Answer (score 1):

As per my understanding of your requirement your best option is: [Identifier for Vendor (IDFV)](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uidevice/1620059-identifierforvendor)

[Identifier for Vendor (IDFV)](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uidevice/1620059-identifierforvendor) change when all apps from the same vendor are removed. If the vendor has only one app means this ID can change if you uninstall and reinstall app.

**Third Part Alternative:**

- [FCUUID](https://github.com/fabiocaccamo/FCUUID)

If you are ok with third party solution you can check: [FCUUID](https://github.com/fabiocaccamo/FCUUID)

With [FCUUID](https://github.com/fabiocaccamo/FCUUID) you can generate ID with different level of persistence.

If you need more persistence than Identifier for Vendor (IDFV) use uuidForDevice of FCUUID.

```
//changes only on system reset, this is the best replacement to the good old udid (persistent to device)
+(NSString *)uuidForDevice;
```

You will find a very interesting discussion about different IDs in this post:

- [The Developer’s Guide to Unique Identifiers](https://possiblemobile.com/2013/04/unique-identifiers/)
- [UIDevice uniqueIdentifier Deprecated - What To Do Now?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6993325/uidevice-uniqueidentifier-deprecated-what-to-do-now)
- [iOS unique user identifier](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7273014/ios-unique-user-identifier?noredirect=1&lq=1)

I hope you get some help from this information.