# How to get unqiue id for every device not for every app?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, device, deviceid

I want to know one unique id per device but not for per app in one device.
I am building one framework where I want to use this device id.

Comment: There is no such id available, vender id is the only unique id that u get but that might change if user uninstalls and reinstalls ur app, if you are supporting iOS11 and above, device check API might come handy depending on what exactly you are trying to achieve.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to generate Unique ID of device for iPhone/iPad using Objective-c](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41016762/how-to-generate-unique-id-of-device-for-iphone-ipad-using-objective-c)

Comment: Might be duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41217864/unable-to-have-a-unique-ios-device-as-advertising-identifier-returned-as-000000

Answer (score 1):

get UUID from the iOS device and send it to the server

```
let uuid = NSUUID().UUIDString.lowercaseString
print(uuid)
```

Hope this helps !!!

Comment: UUID is unqiue to app not to device.

Comment: No, UUID isn't even unique, it generates a random string every time it is called

Answer (score 0):

Just create a unique number by yourself and then store it in the device keychain.

Comment: In device keychain If I store in one device, it can't be accessed on every app on that device.

Comment: enable keychain sharing which will allow you to access unique id among apps.

Comment: @Ellen - keychain sharing requires same developer team. For me my framework will be used in different apps signing with different developer team.